# Generics Type 'T' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

Tags: swift, codable

I am trying to use generics in swift to intrepret http response. All The Json responses have the same signature at the top :

```
{
"request": "foo",
"result": "[{},{}....]
}
```

So I am using this :

```
public struct HttpResponse<DATA: Codable>  {
    public let request: Bool?
    public let result: DATA?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case request= "request"
        case result = "result"

     }   ..
```

In My  Network layer:

```
final class Network<T: Decodable> {
 func getItems(_ path: String) -> Observable<HttpResponse<[T]>> {
    let absolutePath = "\(endPoint)/\(path)"
    return RxAlamofire
        .data(.get, absolutePath)
        .debug()
        .observeOn(scheduler)
        .map({ data -> [T] in
            return try JSONDecoder().decode([T].self, from: data)
        })
}
```

I get this error in `Observable<PlutusResponse<[T]>>`

> Generics Type 'T' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

How to correctly use this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a mismatch:

It should be `HttpResponse<DATA: Decodable>` instead of `HttpResponse<DATA: Codable>`, see definition `Network<T: Decodable>`.

Codable declares conformance to both Decodable and Encodable protocols, see the definition of Codable:

```
public typealias Codable = Decodable & Encodable
```

So your HttpResponse expects a generic that conforms to both Decodable and Encodable protocol. But in the definition of Network a generic that conforms only to Decodable is used. Therefore as soon as the compiler checks the method signature of `getItems`, it complains that 'T' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'.